# Google drive api between google compute instance and google drive

Tags: google-drive-api, google-compute-engine

I tried to access Google drive from a python script using Google Drive  API.

- It works from my personal computer, since I can launch a browser to validate the authentification
- It is impossible to make it work on a Google Compute instance (there is no browser, impossibl to transfer the credentials).

Has anyone ever done it ?  Does anyone know how to do it ?
Thanks a lot for any information
N.Mathieu

Answer (score 0):

Use a service account, which does not require a browser nor user interaction.

A service account belongs to an application, not to an individual end user. It can be used in its own, or it can impersonate another user in the domain (see [Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority)).

But in any case, it doesn't require user consent or interaction, and it is useful in situations where there is no browser and where the should not be user interaction.

#### Code sample:

```py
# Copyright 2020 Google LLC.
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import service_account

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'credentials.json'

def getCreds():
    creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
    # Uncomment if you want to impersonate another user:
    # creds = creds.with_subject('impersonated_account@your_domain.com') 
    return creds

def main():
    creds = getCreds()
    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
    # Use service to call Drive API (e.g. service.files().list().execute())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

#### Further reading:

- [Service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts)
- [Creating and enabling service accounts for instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances)
- [Authenticating as a service account](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production)
- [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account)